# Should I get a Macbook Air Haswell i5 8GB

Tags: macbook-pro

Right now I have an older Macbook Pro with the following specs:

```
2.3 GHz i5
4 GB 1333 MHz
Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB
```

And have the possibility to trade my Macbook Pro for a 2013 Haswell Macbook Air with the following specs:

```
1,3-GHz i5
8 GB 1600 MHz
Intel HD Graphics 5000
```

Right now there is no way I can play games on my Macbook Pro. It just can't handle it. Will this be at least a little bit better with the Haswell Processor of the Macbook Air?

Comment: That depends. Do you want to?

Comment: Both!  But, honestly, this question is a bit to subjective for StackExchange.  Please find a way to ask a more specific question.  I recommend asking "What type of macbook would best suit these needs?" And provide a list of specific needs that you need to fulfill in your line of work.

Comment: You're right. I've edited my question. Hope this is more specific.

Comment: Great edit. If you could narrow games, that would be even better. No one would say you couldn't play Minecraft or [Limbo](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/limbo/id481629890?mt=12) on any Mavericks capable hardware, but perhaps GTA or some aggressive GPU hungry games might have frame rates below what some consider ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the Intel HD 5000 is better than a HD 3000 but it's still a integrated chip. So it won't be killer chip you are waiting for.

I suggest you to check some test who include benchmarks like on [AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7085/the-2013-macbook-air-review-13inch/4). The question is what level of performance can satisfy your needs.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for! Im not expecting anything from it. Just wanted to know if it would perform better. Thank you!